# Calling next on an Iterator once vs multiple times

Tags: java, iterator

Why this first version of the code does not work

```
          // returns the longest string in the list (does not work!)

         public static String longest(LinkedList<String> list) {
              Iterator<String> itr = list.iterator();
              String longest = itr.next(); // initialize to first element

              while (itr.hasNext()) {
                  if (itr.next().length() > longest.length()) {
                     longest = itr.next();
                  } 
              }
              return longest;
         }
```

but the second version of the code will ?

```
       // this version of the code is correct

       while (itr.hasNext()) {
           String current = itr.next();
           if (current.length() > longest.length()) {
               longest = current;
           }
       }
```

Comment: Calling .next on the iterator moves to the next element. You called it twice in your while loop.

Comment: each time you call `next()` you are getting a new object.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When your `if` condition is `true`, you are calling `next()` twice:

```
if (itr.next().length() > longest.length()) {
    longest = itr.next();
...
```

Thus, inside the `if` body, you are assigning the length of the **next** value, not the current one, to `longest`.

`Iterator.next()` returns the current value from the collection, but at the same time, advances the iterator to the next element.

Note that your second call to `itr.next()` might throw a `NoSuchElementException` if there is no next element. Always call `Iterator.next()` only **once** after you have checked with `Iterator.hasNext()` whether there is a next element available.

Even better, use the [foreach loop](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html) which handles all the boilerplate:

```
for (String current : list) {
    ....
    // "current" now points to the current element
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Because on the first code, you'll never write the first element down, because you're calling `next()` without using it. Then you call `next()` 2 times in each loop, so you'll get only 1 over 2 result

Answer (score 0):

Count the number of times `next()` is called in the first snipped compared to the second:

```
while (itr.hasNext()) {
    if (itr.next().length() > longest.length()) {
        ^^^^^^^^^^
        longest = itr.next();
                  ^^^^^^^^^^
    }
}
```

compared to

```
while (itr.hasNext()) {
    String current = itr.next();
                     ^^^^^^^^^^
    if (current.length() > longest.length()) {
        longest = current;
    }
}
```

Every time you call `itr.next()`, you advance the iterator another token. So in the first snippet, you only store/compare *every other* token, while in the second snippet you store/compare the *same* token.

Answer (score 0):

in the correct version you call the next method once and it's working well.
but in the first one, you move the cursor twice and the result is different from what you expect.
every time we call next or previous, the cursor moves.